# Matlab Application Compiler omits function call

Tags: matlab, matlab-compiler

I have two *.m files with two functions

function one is `main(folder_path)`
the second one is `calculate(file)`

function `main` calls `calculate`and writes the results to a text file using fprintf

When I run the script in Matlab, it writes correct floating point values to the text file. However, when I use the Application Compiler and create a *.exe file, all results are `NaN`in the text file.

I inserted some debug outputs and noticed, that none of the outputs in `calculate`is printed when using the *.exe. So I guess that the function `calculate`is never called.

Is there any reason for such a behavior? Am I missing anything?

```
% file main.m
function main(folder_path)
wildcard = '*.h5';

files = dir([folder_path , wildcard]);

% store results
[num_files, ~] = size(files);
vec_average = zeros(num_files);

for index = 1:size(files)
    average = calculate([folder_path, files(index).name]);

    % store in vector for matlab plotting
    vec_average(index) = average;
end

% calculate avg value from all files
average = mean(vec_average);

% write to text files, for jenkins plotting
[file, msg] = fopen('average.property', 'w');
if file == -1
    error(msg);
end
fprintf(file, 'YVALUE=%.5f\n', average(1));
fclose(file);
end
```

next file:

```
% file calculate.m
function [average] = calculate(file_path)
% read datasets - loop over h5 file
data = h5read(file_path ,'/datasets' );

num_elements = data.num_elements;
elements = data.elements;

vec_y = [];

for index = 1:size(elements)
    vec_y = [vec_y, elements(i)];
end

average = mean(vec_y);
end
```

Comment: I don't know what to clarify. There is no error message and nothing else, it just works one way and the other way it doesn't. Do you have any specific hint? Do you want to see the full code?

Comment: I read what's in there, but the only thing I can present you is working Matlab code (shortened) which doesn't work after using Application compiler.

Comment: Sure, but at least now we can try it for ourselves, and also see which functions are contained within the MATLAB code; some functions don't compile properly. In this case: I suspect `h5read` is at fault. I'm not familiar with the compiler's inner workings, but that's the function which is not "basic" as such.

Comment: shouldn't this be irrelevant as I'm not using Matlab Coder but Application Compiler?

Answer (score 0):

If `calculate` is never called -> it means that your `files` variable is empty -> are you sure that your are calling the main program the same way?  i.e. is `folder_path` the same in both calls?

If your on windows you can run from a dos prompt and you will see an error/disp/fprintf messages that would normally be written to the terminal (So to help debug add a lot more, e.g. `folder_path`, `num_files` etc...

Comment: yes, I used `disp()` to display the variables in matlab and windows console. All outputs are absolutely identical in Matlab and after compiling. But at the line where `calculate`is called the compiled version does strange things

Comment: You'll need to elaborate on `strange things` - check that the file its trying to read exists - is it throwing an error - if so what error etc....

Comment: The file exists as I used an absolute path that worked in Matlab

The exe is in the same folder and uses the same absolute path in the same format

Comment: You will still need to elaborate on `strange things`.  `h5read` can be compiled so it should work.  We cannot help without more information